# How can I select data from multiple mysql tables in this scenario?

Tags: mysql

Ok I have a bit of a weird scenario, and I can't change the database structure, because I don't have the permission for that. For the problem, i have three tables

**table 1-**

```
  id(int) | name(varchar) | link_id(int) | link_to(tinyint)
..............................................................
    1       | value1        | 1            | 2
    2       | value2        | 3            | 2
    3       | value3        | 1            | 3
    4       | value4        | 2            | 3
    5       | value5        | 3            | 3
```

**table 2-**

```
  id(int)  | data(varchar)
............................
    1       | some1       
    2       | some2       
    3       | some3
```

**table 3-**

```
    id(int) | data(varchar)
............................
    1       | another1       
    2       | another2       
    3       | another3
```

Now let me explain: in `table 1`, `link_id` is the `id` field of either `table 2` or `table 3`, and `link_to` states whether it is linked to table 2 or 3.

Now I need to fetch the combined data from all 3 tables such that, against each `name` field in `table 1`, I get the `data` field from the correct table as defined by the link_id and link_to fields in that row.

Is there any mysql query for achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with a UNION

```
(
SELECT t1.id,t2.data
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.link_id=t2.id AND t1.link_to=2
) UNION (
SELECT t1.id,t3.data
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.link_id=t3.id AND t1.link_to=3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer.
You could also create a stored procedure and allow searches.

```
# stored procedure
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE `search_by_value`(
    in_searchValue VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE jointable INTEGER;

  SELECT link_to INTO jointable FROM table1 WHERE name = in_searchValue;
  IF (jointable = 2) THEN
    SELECT * FROM table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.link_id = t2.id WHERE t1.name = in_searchValue;
  ELSEIF (jointable = 3) THEN
    SELECT * FROM table1 t1 left join table3 t3 on t1.link_id = t3.id WHERE t1.name = in_searchValue;
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER;

# call the sp
call search_by_value('value1');
```