# How to search data from multiple tables using Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables :
`bldr_prjct`,`bldr_prjct_attr`,`bldr_prjct_attr_ref`;

i want to get bldr_prjct data where bldr_prjct attributes are stored in `bldr_prjct_attr`. 
`bldr_prjct_attr_ref` : In this table i have defined values all attributes related to projects :

Screenshots :
`bldr_prjct`

[image]

**`bldr_prjct_attr_ref`** :

[image]

**`bldr_prjct_attr` :**

[image]

My query :

```
SELECT 
    `p`.`ID`,`p`.`PRJCT_NM`,`p`.`SLUG`,`p`.`STS_CD`,
    `p`.`PRJCT_GEO_LT`,`p`.`PRJCT_GEO_LG` 
FROM 
    `bldr_prjct` `p`, `bldr_prjct_attr_ref` `pr`, `bldr_prjct_attr` `pa` 
WHERE 
    `pa`.`REF_ID` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `bldr_prjct_attr_ref` WHERE `PRNT_ID`=3)
```

Comment: have a look at this, this should give you some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023371/how-can-i-select-data-from-multiple-mysql-tables-in-this-scenario?rq=1

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union)

Comment: No screenshots, thanks. Provide proper DDLs

Comment: what is the relationship id of each table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use implicit `JOIN` syntax(comma separated) , use the proper syntax of join, that will help you avoid this kind of mistakes.

You query is not working because you are missing the join relations , you may have to adjust it a bit, i guessed `bldr_prjct` is joined to `bldr_prjct_attr_ref` by `id=prnt_id` although you have prnt_id column in this table, so change it if needed.

```
SELECT `p`.`ID`,`p`.`PRJCT_NM`,`p`.`SLUG`,`p`.`STS_CD`,`p`.`PRJCT_GEO_LT`,`p`.`PRJCT_GEO_LG`
FROM `bldr_prjct` `p`
INNER JOIN `bldr_prjct_attr` `pa`
 ON(`p`.id = `pa`.prnt_id )
INNER JOIN `bldr_prjct_attr_ref` `pr`
 ON(`pa`.ref_id = `pr`.id and `pr`.prnt_id = 3 )
```

Comment: This query is working but has some issue i have two row with same ref_id in  `bldr_prjct_attr` then it gives first row with two time.

Comment: `bldr_prjct ` is joined to `bldr_prjct_attr ` and `bldr_prjct_attr` is joined to `bldr_prjct_attr_ref`.

Comment: So? What is the problem with two rows? its a duplicate row, E.G. all columns are the same? @ManishTiwari

Comment: Thanks Mate, it's working. i was doing something wrong so that's why it gives duplicate rows. Can you explain me how it works ?

Comment: This basically join each table by the connection specified inside the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but your tables don't appear to have any common reference. For instance, table `bldr_prjct_attr_ref` does not include any field pointing to the relevant record in table `bldr_prjct`. If my understanding is correct, you will have to alter these tables to allow some time of cross-referencing. For instance, add to table `bldr_prjct_attr_ref` a field (column) `bldr_prjct_ID` that points to the corresponding record in table `bldr_prjct`.
There is one field in the third table that **appears** to reference a record in the first, but when you issue a SELECT of three tables and one of them returns an empty result, then the overall select returns empty.